# MySQL Check if date range is in date range

Tags: mysql, date-range

Having trouble making a SQL query for a small booking system, i have a table containing two entries which holds two different dates and a number.

```
Nr    DateFrom      DateTo
----------------------------
1    2015-01-01   2015-01-03
2    2015-01-05   2015-01-08
```

I want to query where i can enter two different dates and only return the number of the date range in the table that doesn't collide with the entered date range.

For example if i enter the dates 2015-01-02 and 2015-01-04 it would return Nr 2 and
2015-01-05 and 2015-01-08 would return Nr 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DateFrom > @rangeEnd OR DateTo < @rangeBegin
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/135ff/6)

Comment: Thank you! But the problem now is that entering range 2015-01-01 to 2015-01-04 would return Nr 1 which i would not like it to do.

Comment: No it doesn't. See the sqlfiddle demo I just added.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I solved using this type of query.

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE (@rangeBegin <= DateFrom OR @rangeEnd >= DateTo) AND (@rangeBegin between DateFrom AND DateTo OR @rangeEnd between DateFrom AND DateTo)
```