# How to check if optional date range is between optional date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-range

I am having trouble writting a query to check if every delivery was within the date range of a projet.
I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29727998/mysql-check-if-date-range-is-in-date-range) but my date range has not necessarily ended, in which case endDate is null.

Both my projet and delivery table contain a startDate and an endDate with a constraint to make sure the endDate is either null or after startDate.

This is my select:

```
SELECT *
FROM Projet
    INNER JOIN Delivery ON Delivery.ProjetId = Projet.ProjetId
```

I've tried using `BETWEEN` but because of the possible `NULL` I'm missing any ongoing projects.

```
WHERE Delivery.startDate BETWEEN Projet.startDate AND Projet.endDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Projet p
INNER JOIN Delivery d ON d.ProjetId = p.ProjetId
WHERE d.startDate >= p.startDate
  AND (p.endDate is null
    OR p.endDate is not null
    AND (d.endDate is null OR d.endDate <= p.endDate)
  )
```

Comment: Isn't the `(p.endDate is OR p.endDate is not null)` redundant?

Comment: @Halhex Yep, it's redundant. I decided to leave it there just for clarity.